# How to check LDAP password hash method (password authentication) in java?

Tags: java, authentication, hash, passwords, ldap

I need to synchronize users kept in my database in my java application with those in specific location in active directory. I want to use the same authentication in my server application so I can copy hash of passwords from ldap to my database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider authenticating your users to A/D instead of trying to maintain synchronization between A/D and your database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Spring Security:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html